# bind data from several tables to specific control

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Q:

I have the following case and i need the best performance answer:

i will use advanced control like gridview or schedule , and the data that is supposed to be bound to this control is : data from set of tables in my database.not a single table.

what is the best form for this data?

what i thought about at first is:

stored procedure ,contains my logic (and i wanna to ask here about what is the best performance also)use temporary table or joins or ... etc.

what are the possible solutions and more performance rather than stored procedure( as this is a web application many users will use it).
i will be grateful if there is an example to clarify the idea.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way would be to join the tables in an sql stored procedure, performance is not typically an issue unless you are joining many many tables or using a number of nested select statements.

However, if you really need an alternative, you could load data from each table individually (possibly into representative objects i.e. a user object for each row of data from the user table) and then create a data structure to house a combination of the data (i.e. if you have user objects and schedule objects, you could create a UserSchedule object) then you could bind your control to a list of these secondary objects.

**EDIT**

Since you seem to really not want to use stored procs. How about a compromise?
You could use LINQ to entities to join multiple sets of data within C# after getting them all from the DB separately.

Here is an example:

```
ObjectSet<SalesOrderHeader> orders = context.SalesOrderHeaders;
ObjectSet<SalesOrderDetail> details = context.SalesOrderDetails;

var query =
    from order in orders
    join detail in details
    on order.SalesOrderID
    equals detail.SalesOrderID into orderGroup
    select new
    {
        CustomerID = order.SalesOrderID,
        OrderCount = orderGroup.Count()
    };
```

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266.aspx) is a link to more info.

Comment: please, can u clarify what u mean by "structure to house a combination of the data"

Comment: I mean to create a class that contains a property for each of the data items that you need to display in your grid. You will then populate one of these objects for each row you want to display, and then bind your control to a list of these objects. Keep in mind, however, that this will likely not be faster than using a stored procedure on joined tables with proper indexing.

Comment: I have updated my answer to fit what you want a little bit better

Answer (score 1):

If the information in the tables have any common identifier you should use a Join, directly or through a stored procedure.

With the right indexes performance will not be an issue I believe, if you had the amount of data that would cause a problem you would probably have mentioned it as we then would be speaking of massive amounts of data, millions of rows at least.

If you do get performance issues it's likely due to missing or bad indexes or a bad query, and then you could return with a specific question on how to optimize that query :)

If on the other hand the data does not lend it self to joins, maybe you need to process the data from one table to know what to link with in the others then you could create classes to store the data in c# while doing the matching.

If you are using at least 3.5 of c# you could use Linq to join the resulting datastructures after parsing the data.

If you are using c# 2.0, you could either go with all stored procedure for the matching and maybe use temporary tables that you join, or table variables or maybe a table valued function that parses one table and returns a new table that you could join on.